# How can I render the postgis layer to the openlayers map viewer?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openlayers-2

I have a postgres table which is storing the dynamic GPS point data. The geom column has been created. Is it possible to render the last 10 mins GPS data to the OpenLayers map? Is there an example?

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question. You can do it quite easily using ST_ASGeoJSON on the server and OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON read on the client, with an ajax call in a loop to get the data from the server. There are many other ways, but you would need to narrow down your requirements a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data from the server in geoJSON format. I can get you an example in PHP if you want, but I think there are plenty examples around.

Then in Javascript, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {

        $.get("datasource.php", function (data) {

            if ( !data.error ) {

                vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                });

                result = vector_format.read(data);
                vectorLayer.destroyFeatures();
                vectorLayer.addFeatures(result);
                vectorLayer.redraw();
            }

        }, "json");

    }, 600000);
});
```